# Problems with Date using Calendar - Java

Tags: java, calendar

I have a problem when I try use Calendar. 
Look:

```
public static Calendar novaData(Calendar originDate, Integer amountMonth) {
    System.out.println("Origin date: " + originDate.getTime() + " - Add " + amountMonth + " Months");
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(originDate.getTimeZone());
    date.add(Calendar.MONTH, amountMonth);
    System.out.println(date.getTime());
    return date;
}
```

Now, the console:
[image]

In this method, I'll set a date and the amount of month I'm going to add to that date. The problem is there and the day is coming like today (18) and not day 1 as I passed. The expected result is May / 01/2019 - Jun / 01/2019 - Jul / 01/2019

Comment: When you created the `date` object using the `GregorianCalendar`, you only specified a timezone. So it will use the current time: [Constructs a GregorianCalendar based on the current time in the given time zone with the default FORMAT locale.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar-java.util.TimeZone-).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    LocalDate originDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MAY, 1);
    for (int amountMonth = 1; amountMonth <= 3; amountMonth++) {
        System.out.println("Origin date: " + originDate + " - Add " + amountMonth + " Months");
        System.out.println(originDate.plusMonths(amountMonth));
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> Origin date: 2019-05-01 - Add 1 Months
> 2019-06-01
> Origin date: 2019-05-01 - Add 2 Months
> 2019-07-01
> Origin date: 2019-05-01 - Add 3 Months
> 2019-08-01
> ```

I gather from your desired output that you are only interested in the date, not the time of day nor the time zone. If so, the `LocalDate` class is the correct class to use.

If you are only interested in the month, not the day of month, use `YearMonth` instead of `LocalDate`. The code will be the same except for the declaration and initialization:

```
    YearMonth originDate = YearMonth.of(2019, Month.MAY);
```

> ```
> Origin date: 2019-05 - Add 1 Months
> 2019-06
> (etc.)
> ```

Don’t use `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. On top of that they carry with each object a time of day, a time zone, a week scheme and more, all of which I don’t think you need and that will only risk confusing those that read your code.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

First, if at all possible consider using the newer Java Date objects. See, e.g., [this blog](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro).

However, the specific issue of the OP is that the `new GregorianCalendar` call [will create based upon the current date/time of the user](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar-java.util.TimeZone-). It is not using the specified date/time of the originDate.

One way to adjust the code would be:

```
public static Calendar novaData(Calendar originDate, Integer amountMonth) {
    System.out.println("Origin date: " + originDate.getTime() + " - Add " + amountMonth + " Months");
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.setTime(originDate.getTime());
    date.setTimeZone(originDate.getTimeZone());

    date.add(Calendar.MONTH, amountMonth);
    System.out.println(date.getTime());

    return date;
}
```

Based upon the test input, the output moves the month forward. [See it here](https://ideone.com/cPF2yJ)

> Origin date: Sat May 18 18:01:21 GMT 2019 - Add 0 Months
>   Sat May 18 18:01:21 GMT 2019
>   Origin date: Sat May 18 18:01:21 GMT 2019 - Add 1 Months
>   Tue Jun 18 18:01:21 GMT 2019
>   Origin date: Sat May 18 18:01:21 GMT 2019 - Add 2 Months
>   Thu Jul 18 18:01:21 GMT 2019

Please note that issues with leap years, negative amounts, etc. are not fully considered.